# Need Help Combining time.sleep with multiprocessing in python 3

Tags: process, python-3.x, sleep

Making a turn based game using python 3. I want 2 characters (foe & enemy) to attack, pause based on random+speed, then attack again if they are still alive.

The problem I am running into is the time.sleep freezes both modules, not 1 or the other. Any suggestions to make this work effectively?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import random

def timing1():  
    speed=60#SPEED IS NORMALLY A KEY FROM LIST, USING 60 FOR EXAMPLE  
    sleeptime=36/((random.randint(1,20)+speed)/5)  
    print (sleeptime)  
    time.sleep(sleeptime)  
    input('HERO ACTION')  

def timing2():  
    speed=45  
    sleeptime=36/((random.randint(1,20)+speed)/5)  
    print (sleeptime)  
    time.sleep(sleeptime)  
    input('FOE ACTION')  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    p1=Process(target=timing1)  
    p1.start()  
    p2=Process(target=timing2)  
    p2.start()  
    p1.join()  
    p2.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

After a single turn the processes exit in your code. Your main process waits for both processes to exit by calling `.join()` on them i.e., `time.sleep()` doesn't freeze other processes.

Add `while True:` at the top of `timing*()` functions to make multiple moves.

You don't need multiple processes here. You could use threads or even a single thread to implement turns.

Comment: Thank you. New at this, but getting a hang on it.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on J.F.

My general advice about threading is to only introduce it if absolutely necessary.

- You are literally blocking on low-level I/O and there are no alternatives but using native threads.
- You are are hitting calculation limits and need to utilize more cores, in which case python due to it's [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) might work against you anyways.

As an alternative, utilize a library which supplies a scheduler like [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) or [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) that does not rely on native threads for scheduling events.

**gevent**

You can write your game in a manner with a threaded model in mind, but not having to worry about resource contention among threads.
You do have to keep in mind to use the gevent versions of [various functions](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#useful-general-functions) like *sleep* in your example.

```
import random
import gevent


def hero():
    speed = 60
    sleeptime = 36 / ((random.randint(1, 20) + speed) / 5)
    print (sleeptime)
    gevent.sleep(sleeptime)
    input('HERO ACTION')


def foe():
    speed = 45
    sleeptime = 36 / ((random.randint(1, 20) + speed) / 5)
    print (sleeptime)
    gevent.sleep(sleeptime)
    input('FOE ACTION')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    heroThread = gevent.Greenlet(hero)
    foeThread = gevent.Greenlet(foe)

    heroThread.start()
    foeThread.start()

    gevent.joinall([heroThread, foeThread])
```

**twisted**

Supplies an event reactor which is written in pure python and makes no pretense in being anything more or less than a single threaded event reactor (a.k.a. an [Event Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)).
This would require a bigger rewrite of your example.

```
import random
from twisted.internet import reactor


def heroAction():
    input('HERO ACTION')


def heroStart():
    speed = 60
    sleeptime = 36 / ((random.randint(1, 20) + speed) / 5)
    print (sleeptime)
    reactor.callLater(sleeptime, heroAction)


def foeAction():
    input('FOE ACTION')


def foeStart():
    speed = 45
    sleeptime = 36 / ((random.randint(1, 20) + speed) / 5)
    print (sleeptime)
    reactor.callLater(sleeptime, foeAction)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Call when the reactor has started.
    reactor.callWhenRunning(heroStart)
    reactor.callWhenRunning(foeStart)
    reactor.run()
```

Note that the twisted reactor will not shut down when it has nothing left to do, this is explicitly left to the programmer.

**Rolling your Own**

It might be interesting for learning purposes to write your own scheduler, or you might have requirements in your game like fairness which require it.
A good starting point would be to look at [another minimalistic scheduler](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/sched.py) for inspiration.